# Launching an application from a batch file through White

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, white-framework

I am trying to have White detect an application that starts from a batch file. The current code I have is:

```
Application application = Application.Launch(@"C:\WINNT\system32\calc.exe");
```

This works fine for openning applications from its .exe, but when I tried:

```
Application application = Application.Launch(@"C:\WINNT\system32\test.bat");
```

It did not launch the .bat. I am assuming even if the ,bat ran,the application would be assign to cmd.exe instead of my actual application from the batch. Is there any way for me to set the application such that it search for the application from the process tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try launching with this command line instead:

```
@"C:\WINNT\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\WINNT\system32\test.bat"
```

Cmd.exe is the EXE that interprets .bat or .cmd script files.